# Laravel log messages/errors on daily basis and type wise

Tags: logging, laravel-5

Is there any solution in Laravel to log all the messages type wise and on daily basis?

Something like below:

- laravel-2017-08-**09**-info.log
- laravel-2017-08-09-error.log
- laravel-2017-08-09-critical.log
- laravel-2017-08-**10**-info.log
- laravel-2017-08-**10**-error.log

The daily Laravel log creates only 1 file but not type wise. There are other solutions available in stack overflow but they create type wise files but not on daily basis.

Comment: check this one https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/advance-logging-with-laravel-and-monolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there was no out of box support from Laravel and this kind of plugin was yet to develop (at least this is what I could find out).

It may be against the rule to give references of own publications/materials, in that case apologies in advance but I have created my own small [work](https://github.com/ravimaniyar/meticulous-lara-logger) and pushed to my GIT hub repository. You can check that out and let me know if any issues in the code.

**EDIT:**

To those, who does not want to integrate a module can quickly look into following steps:

1. Open your config/logging.php and add custom index which indicates a custom driver and handler class.
2. Set LOG_CHANNEL in env file as custom.
3. Create App\Logging directory and add Logger and Handler files which will invoke custom handler function whenever you use `Log` class of Laravel.
4. Run command `composer dump-autoload`

For more information, you can look into the GIT hub repository I have provided above and log issues/enhancements over there.

Comment: It is not against the rules to answer own questions (which can also include self-written code, of course). But it would make sense to include essential parts of the solution into the answer itself. In your case that is basically `MeticulousLogger.php`, `MeticulousLoggerHandler.php` and the custom logging driver configuration within `config/logging.php`.

Comment: Ok @Namoshek - I will edit it and provide more details in my answer itself. Thanks.